# ifconfig does not show enp1s0 on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, ifconfig

I am using linux mint

```
ifconfig
```

does not show enp1s0. it just shows

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::c364:e1b0:d52d:657f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:77:c5:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 164217  bytes 182814329 (182.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50303  bytes 6603681 (6.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9297  bytes 817576 (817.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9297  bytes 817576 (817.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

i changed the network adapter from NAT to bridged adapter.
i enter this command to enable it incase it is disabled by default.

```
ifup enp1s0
```

got this message:

```
Unknown interface enp1s0
```

network adapter

```
 sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: enp0s3
       version: 02
       serial: 08:00:27:77:c5:b8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.10 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f1200000-f121ffff ioport:d020(size=8)
```

Comment: cam you post your configuration? atm it's like looking for a needle in a haystack

Comment: /etc/host is set. from virtual settings network adapter is set to bridged adapter and set the adapter. this is the same configurations as i did for kali linux, but with kali i got the result enp1s0. i think maybe mint does not show that property so i searched google about it but could not find anything.

Comment: Do you have any reason why that particular interface _should_ show up? Could you show a bit of configuration?

Comment: Also, please post the output of `sudo lspci -nn -s1:0.0` to verify the type of the network adapter.

Comment: Do you have a reason why `enp1s0` should exist? Do you have two interfaces?

Comment: in kali linux when i run this code it shows but linux mint does not

Comment: @telcoM your command did not work. sudo lshw -C network this worked

Comment: So it confirmed that there is currently no network interface in PCI bus location 1:0.0, which is what name `enp1s0` means. That's what I actually expected. The new-style network interface names reflect PCI device identifiers: `enpXsY` means PCI device X:Y.0, and `enpXsYfZ` would be PCI X:Y.Z where Z != 0. Note that the network interface names use base-10 in their numbers, while the PCI bus identifiers are usually hexadecimal (base-16). In a VirtualBox VM, the first virtual NIC is usually 00:03.0 = `enp0s3`. If you configure a second virtual NIC, it will usually be 00:08:0 = `enp0s8`.

Answer (score 1):

If interface is not configured in */etc/network/interfaces* it's not shown in **ifconfig** output by default, but you can check it:

```
~$: ifconfig -a
~$: ip address show
```

To check available interfaces:

```
~$: ls /sys/class/net
```